# Looping through array inside of stuct

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, syntax, struct

I'm a student, learning pointers for the first time.  My assignment doesn't allow the use of string classes and should be using pointer notation to access all elements within an array (no []).

Why am I not able to access an array inside of a struct via pointers?  Is my syntax off?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct person
{
    int favNums[4];
};

// Notation works here
void strCopy(char *from, char *to, int len)
{        
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        *(to + i) = *(from + i);
    }
}

// But doesn't work here
void sayNumsPointerNotation(person peep)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        //cout << peep.*(favNums + i) << endl;
    }
}

// Would like to accomplish this.
void sayNums(person peep)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        cout << peep.favNums[i] << endl;
    }
}

int main() 
{
    // Array outside of struct
    char from[5] = "Word";
    char to[5];
    strCopy(from, to, 5);
    cout << to << endl << endl;

    // Array inside of struct non-pointer
    person peep;
    peep.favNums[0] = 0;
    peep.favNums[1] = 1;
    peep.favNums[2] = 2;
    peep.favNums[3] = 3;

    sayNums(peep);
    cout << endl;

    sayNumsPointerNotation(peep);
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: Any reason for rewriting `memcpy` (badly) and re-naming it deceptively similar to `strcpy`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
cout << peep.*(favNums + i) << endl;
```

Try this:

```
cout << *(peep.favNums + i) << endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work, hopefully you understand what was wrong.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct person
{
    int favNums[4];
};

// Notation works here 
void strCopy(char *from, char *to, int len)
{        
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        *(to + i) = *(from + i);
    }
}

// But doesn't work here (now it works)
void sayNumsPointerNotation(person* peep)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        cout << *(peep->favNums + i) << endl;
    }
}

// Would like to accomplish this.
void sayNums(person peep)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        cout << peep.favNums[i] << endl;
    }
}

int main() 
{
    // Array outside of struct
    char from[5] = "Word";
    char to[5];
    strCopy(from, to, 5);
    cout << to << endl << endl;

    // Array inside of struct non-pointer
    person peep;
    peep.favNums[0] = 0;
    peep.favNums[1] = 1;
    peep.favNums[2] = 2;
    peep.favNums[3] = 3;

    sayNums(peep);
    cout << endl;

    sayNumsPointerNotation(&peep);
    cout << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
cout << *(peep.favNums + i) << endl;
```

`.*`, on the other hand, is a "member pointer", and means something different.